# How to implement HTML5 pattern to only accept specific characters

Tags: html, regex

I want to implement this pattern to only accept one letter, being the possibilities: "M,m,F or f". I tried writing this: `pattern="[M][m][F][f]{1}"`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
pattern="[MmFf]"
```

Answer (score 0):

“[abc]” Matches only a single character from set of given characters.
so you need `[MmFf]`